# does google charge for purchases in app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am building a free android app in which there should be a "store" where you can buy some item.
The plan is that user could pay for it using paypal or something. Now my question is, does playstore takes some percentage for such transaction? And if so, how much does it take?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google charges 30% for every transaction. Details can be checked [here](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en).

Comment: ok, if I got this right, google charges fee when purchasing an app, but what I need is charging for selling stuff from app. For example, I am selling map routes in my app, will google charge fee?

Comment: by word every transaction I mean even if you are selling digital content through Google in-app,google will charge 30% of your product price. In your case yes google will charge.

Comment: Google will charge only if you are using In-App purchase. Not in the case of any other way of payment like PayPal.

Comment: For subscriptions this goes down to 15% after a year of subscriptions.

Comment: What happens if it is hotel app?

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is correct, but we should take into consideration another aspect about purchasing via smartphone/tablet. This recalls @JaranJhanjee's downvoted answer which is wrong but **contains a little important truth**

The 30% fee is charged by Google for in-app purchases according to their [terms](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html)

---

- Paid and Free Apps

  - App purchases: Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play must do so by using Google Play's payment system.
  - In-app purchases:

    - Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.
    - Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
      where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or
      where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on other music players).

---

Google always charges the 30% via its in-app billing API. But there are cases **in which such an API should be avoided** to not incur in an excessive charging

- If navigator maps are usable across more devices (especially non-Android devices like iPhones o MS Phones)
- If maps will be delivered packaged in an SD card at the customer's home address

In such cases, the seller **is allowed** to implement a different payment gateway like [Google Wallet API](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial) or PayPal

Comment: one question, if we use some other payment type (other than the google play in-app billing service) inside the app, for itens that are not exclusive to the android app, the google will also charge the 30%?

Comment: Google always charges 30%. It's up to the developer to choose a cheaper gateway if eligible

Comment: I would also like to know the ansewr to the question by @xanexpt. I don't think usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ answered it. If you're using an alternative payment type to Google Play's in-app billing (e.g. PayPal) for an item and that item is not exclusive to the Android version of your app, does that fulfill the restriction that you must be able to consume that content "outside of the app itself". E.g. an upgrade to pro status that applies to the iOS version of the app as well. Can I use paypal for this?

Comment: Answer is simple. Routing payments via In App Billing **is charged 30%** always and automatically. Other payment gateways, if not in violation of ToS, **is never charged anything to Google**. Your "pro upgrade" that applies to the iOS version too, *in my interpretation of Android ToS*, is eligible for PayPal processing

Answer (score 7):

Refer below link for google charges.

```
You receive 70% of the payment. The remaining 30% goes to the distribution partner and operating fees.
```

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

> For apps and in-app products offered through Google Play, the
>   transaction fee is equivalent to 30% of the price. You receive 70% of
>   the payment. The remaining 30% goes to the distribution partner and
>   operating fees.
>
> As of January 1, 2018, the transaction fee for subscription products
>   decreases to 15% for any subscribers you retain after 12 paid months.
>   If a subscriber has been active as of this date, that time will be
>   counted. For example, if a subscriber has been active for 4 months,
>   the transaction fee will be reduced to 15% after 8 more paid months.

[Reference](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en)