# Android Play store policy on virtual content

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

This is not a programming question per say. Please redirect me to proper place in case this does not fit stackoverflow's guidelines.

I am working on an app where people can consume virtual content (say an ebook) after paying for it. Now the same content (once the user has downloaded it) can be viewed (free of cost) on different devices. In such a scenario, is it mandatory for me to use Google's payment gateway?

As per Google's guidelines (http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#payments), for anything which can be used outside the play store (like an .mp3) does not require Google's payment gateway.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789246/android-play-store-policy-for-digital-content

In any case, how reading an ebook (for example) different from .mp3 ?

Comment: if you provide content to users for ebooks in your application then go for in app purchase, it is easy to use and easy to handle. And google is now also provided different section for the ebook itself. you just have to put your ebook as paid on play store and just pass the intent to the play store in app, play store will handle all the transaction and Google ebook app installation process and etc.

Comment: @Maulik - Its convenient to use Google's existing in-app purchase but perhaps not commercially viable. The only problem is the 30% cut that Google charges. In case, the product is not categorized as virtual (as in the case of .mp3), I can forego this 30%. This is the main issue.

Comment: Google will charge user on transaction base. check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808794/does-google-charge-for-purchases-in-app and https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en. Let me know if you still have query.

Comment: @Maulik-Google's policy states that "Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (buying songs that can be played on other music players). M question is since my virtual content can be consumed outside the app (on other devices say iOS/Windows phone, etc.), do I still need to use Google Play's in-app billing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Play Store policy for digital content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789246/android-play-store-policy-for-digital-content)

Comment: questions about Terms of Service, policies are offtopic