# Do google playstore charge apps for selling non digital goods such as groceries etc

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am building a free android app from which one can buy daily use items such as groceries. Users would have online payment options in app. Will Google play-store charge me per purchase/transaction made in app ? Im confused on what purchases are treated as in-app purchases and Service fees is applied.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808794/does-google-charge-for-purchases-in-app) question but want to be specific on non digital content sale in app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

You can find information about it here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738

Here are some examples of products not currently supported by Google Play In-App Billing according to the support page:

> Retail merchandise, such as groceries, clothing, housewares and electronics.
> Service fees, including taxi and transportation services, cleaning services, food delivery, airfare and event tickets.
> One-time membership fees or recurring dues, including gym memberships, loyalty programmes or clubs offering accessories, clothing or other physical products.
> One-off payments, including peer-to-peer payments, online auctions and donations.
> Electronic bill payment, including credit card bills, utilities and cable or telecommunications services.